# Does spring.ftl (freemarker bindings) support nested paths? How?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

How can I write the freemarker templates like this:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as s>

<@s.form path="object" action="/new.do" method="POST">
    <@s.formInput "name"/> <!-- I want this resolved as "object.name" -->
    <!--
        100s of other properties...
      -->
</@s.form>
```

instead of this:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as s>

<form action="/new.do" method="POST">
    <@s.formInput "object.name"/>
    <!--
        100s of other properties...
      -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the object like this:

```
<@s.bind "object"/>
```

Then you can use your first example

```
<@s.formInput "name"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I got a
"Method public org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException."

I noticed that in the formInput macro it calls bind with the given path again, replacing the previous one, I suppose...

I'm using the spring.ftl provided with spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Thanks for any further suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [spring.ftl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/spring.ftl) doesn't support nested paths. It is conceivable that one could write one's own `nestedPath` macro that functioned similar to the [nestedPath JSP tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/NestedPathTag.html). You'd probably need a `bind` macro that recognized it as well, and maybe more to get all the form input macros working.

Or, maybe it's possible to import and use the JSP tags themselves instead of spring.ftl or custom macros.